# Can not change color of UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicolor

I'm trying to change the background-, tint-, and barTintColor of my searchBar... I've tried so many different ways but none of them worked. I even tried setting my GlobalTintColor to the yellow I want.

Current Code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //UISearchController
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.96, blue:0.02, alpha:1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.96, blue:0.02, alpha:1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.36, green:0.39, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Users"

    if #available(iOS 9.1, *) {
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    } else {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
    self.navigationItem.titleView?.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
}
```

Do I have anything set wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Do it this way:

```
func SearchBarAppearence() {
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .black
    searchController.searchBar.setValue("text of button", forKey:"_cancelButtonText")
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white]
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "text of searchbar", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont(name: IRAN_SANS_MOBILE_FONT, size: 14)!]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: IRAN_SANS_MOBILE_FONT, size: 14)!], for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: this didn't made any difference

Comment: the code is tested can i see the whole viewcontroller

Comment: well, I got it working by creating a complete new searcher - don't know where the error was, although thank you for your help